# Client same socket descriptors

Tags: c, linux, client-server

I have a server-client system (concurrent server).  I have different clients on different machines.  I am trying to send a notification to particular clients.  However, I have a problem as the clients all have the same socket descriptor.  On both computers, the clients have a socket descriptor of 3 and at the server a sd of 5.  Can someone please tell me how I can identify these different clients and why is this happening?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid;
    int buff_size = 1024;
    char buff[buff_size];
    int listen_fd, client_conn;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int server_port = 5001;
    char remote_file[255];

    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (listen_fd < 0) {
        perror("Socket cannot be opened");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*Turning off address checking in order to allow port numbers to be
      reused before the TIME_WAIT. Otherwise it will not be possible to bind
      in a very short time after the server has been shut down*/
    int on = 1;
    int status = setsockopt(listen_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                            (const char *) &on, sizeof(on));

    if (status == -1) {
        perror("Failed to Reuse Address on Binding");
    }

    // Initialise socket structure
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Accept connections from any address
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);

    // Bind the host address
    if (bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))
        < 0) {
        perror("ERROR on binding");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Start listening for the clients, here process will
    // go in sleep mode and will wait for the incoming connection
    listen(listen_fd, 5);

    while (1) {
        //Accepting client connection
        client_conn = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);

        if (client_conn < 0) {
            perror("Client was not accepted...");
            exit(1);
        }

        if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
            close(listen_fd);
            bzero(buff, buff_size);

            while ((bytes_read = read(client_conn, buff, buff_size)) > 0) {

                fclose(file);
            }

        }

        //Terminating child process and closing socket
        close(client_conn);
        exit(0);

        bzero(buff, buff_size);

    }

    //parent process closing socket connection
    close(client_conn);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's normal for the clients. Socket descriptors are local to the process, so their 3 descriptors are all different. Just like they each have their own FD 0 for `stdin`. But if you have the same socket descriptor in one server process for different concurrent clients, you're doing something wrong. Post your server code.

Comment: I inserted some skeleton code maybe you can identify the problem of having same socket descriptor in one server process for different clients

Comment: Why do you have `main()` inside a brace? There's also an extra close brace at the end.

Comment: Thats by mistake barmar sry

Comment: I still don't think you copied the code correctly. The code with comment `//Terminating child process` is outside the `if` block, so it runs in both the parent and child. And you have `return 0` at the end, outside the `main()` function.

Answer (score 1):

After the server forks a child it does `close(client_conn)`. When `accept` assigns a socket descriptor to the new connection, it uses the lowest closed descriptor. Since you closed the socket earlier, it can be used for the next client that comes in.

This isn't a problem, because the connections are being managed by the child processes. They each have their own descriptor `5`, and they don't interfere with each other.

Comment: However, I am closing the clien_conn at the end...I am only close listen_fd after the fork()

Comment: You really need to copy the code correctly. The blocks are all messed up in the code you posted, so I can't tell what you're really doing.

Comment: You're closing `listen_fd` in the child, you're closing `client_conn` in the parent. This is the correct way to do it. The child doesn't listen for new connections, and the parent doesn't do anything with the new connection that was just opened.

Comment: So its correct right? ...so how do you think I should identify a client from another, when I have same socket descriptors on both sides? Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Why do you need to identify them? Each client is being managed by a different child process. So as far as they're concerned, there's just one client, there's nothing they have to distinguish?

Comment: Yes but I am creating a table to store the socket descriptor of each client & the path of the file each of the clients are mapping to.  I.e. a struct of sd & filepath.  At a certain point I wish to update specific clients mapping to a specific file.  That is why I wish to identify the clients.

Comment: Then you need to keep the socket open in the parent, and put them in an array. The parent's `SIGCHLD` handler then will have to close the socket associated with that child.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the client address & port returned to you by `accept`.  Currently you are passing a null

> client_conn = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);

however just add a few lines like

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

int len = sizeof(cli_addr);
client_conn = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &len);
```

and you have the client info in cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr and cli_addr.sin_port.

You can get the pid of the child processing the connection from the return code of fork.  That should give you all the information you need to create a table.